# Is this a legit solution to Problem 1 in Section 21 of Munkres's Topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Problem**: Let $A\subset X$. If $d$ is a metric for the topology of $X$, show that $d|A\times A$ is a metric for the subspace topology on A.

**Thoughts**: It seems like it boils down to the question: $U\cap A$ (where $U$ is open in $X$) is open in the subspace topology on $A$, is it also open in the metric topology induced by $\tilde{d}=d|A\times A$?

**Proof (corrected)**: Let $y\in U\cap A$ (an arbitrary member of $U\cap A$). Since $y\in U$ and $U$ is open in $X$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $B_d(y,\delta)\subset U$. Also, $y\in A$, hence $y\in B_d(y,\delta)\cap A$. What is this $B_d(y,\delta)\cap A$? It is a set of points that lie in $A$ that are less than "distance" $\delta$ away from this arbitrarily chosen $y$. By definition, it is $B_\tilde{d}(y,\delta)$ which, in turn, is a subset of $U\cap A$. Therefore, we just showed that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $B_\tilde{d}(y,\delta)\subset U\cap A$. Hence $U\cap A$ is open in the metric topology induced by $\tilde{d}$.

**Proof (incorrect)**: Let $y\in U\cap A$. Since $y\in U$ and $U$ is open in $X$, there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that $B_d(y,\delta_1)\subset U$. Now, $y\in A$ and $A$ is open in the subspace $A$, therefore, there exists a $\delta_2>0$ such that $B_\tilde{d}(y,\delta_2)\subset A$. Pick $\delta = \textrm{min}(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. Then, $B_d(y,\delta)=B_\tilde{d}(y,\delta)\subset U \cap A$. This tells us that $U\cap A$ is open in the metric topology.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly correct. However, the $\delta_2$ is unnecessary. Every $\tilde d$-ball is contained in $A$ by definition.

More importantly, it is not generally true that $B_d(y,\delta)=B_\tilde{d}(y,\delta)$ (for example, if $A$ is a line in $X=\mathbf R^2$, this is always false). What is true is that $B_\tilde{d}(y,\delta)=B_d(y,\delta)\cap A$. If this is not obvious to you, you should prove this first.

Comment: I used $B_d(y,\delta)$=$B_\tilde{d}(y,\delta)$ because it is true for this ball that lies in $A$ (along with it lying in $U$). Does this make it true?

Comment: There is no reason for the $d$-ball to lie in $A$. Consider a line in the plane.

Comment: Oh, that is true. Just so I understand this problem correctly -  are the $d$-ball and $\tilde{d}$-ball the same for those sets that lie in A?

Comment: @DonaldObama: No. A $\tilde d$-ball is the intersection of the corresponding $d$-ball with $A$. They are only equal if the $d$-ball is contained in $A$ (which is only possible if the centre is in the interior of $A$.

Comment: Thank you, @tomasz. Can you check the corrected proof now? I updated it.

Comment: @DonaldObama: Seems okay